# Can't reach this page VS 2015

Tags: c#

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and am trying to run a "sample" project I got from a fellow developer.  When I try to run his project from within Visual Studio 2015, I get this error:

[image]

I've placed a breakpoint in the *default.aspx.cs* file in *page_Load* which is never reached. I also placed a breakpoint in file *Global.asax.cs* in *Application_Start* and the breakpoint is never reached.

So I'm guessing there is either a Web.Config entry I need to add/change and/or project property setting I need to change.  The project does have a Start Action = Specific Page (default.aspx) and Servers section = IIS Express with Project URL = https://localhost:49170/.

There aren't any missing project references. Why am I getting this error as soon as I hit "Run" in Visual Studio 2015 (using [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11))?

Comment: Do you experience this issue in Chrome?  I've read this is an MS issue with the browser.  Try in Chrome or Firefox to at least isolate the issue and so you can keep going with your project.

Comment: Yes, same problem with slightly different error message "This site can't be reached ... ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".  But to be clear, the issue is with just this single solution.  Solutions/Projects I've created in VS 2015 are working fine.

Comment: Ok, are you using IIS Express?  If so, can you validate that the localhost:49170 appears as a running site?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are hitting https instead of http.  Can you try changing this to http for now just to rule ssl out?

Comment: Yes IIS Express per my original post ... tried HTTP: no different, same error.

Comment: Right-click on the project in VS -> Properties -> Web -> Create Virtual Directory.  Make sure http://localhost:49170 is in the Project URL textbox.

Comment: Yes had tried the Virtual Directory option also and still same error.  Has me stumped ... it seems that I can't run solutions/projects NOT created on my PC.

Comment: Ok, I know you said you are using IIS Express but have you checked that the port you are calling is listening (in this case 49170)?  If the solution/project was created on another machine it would use the port setup on that machine and the port would be different on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing the port to another port that I successfully used with other projects/solutions I've created on my PC ... sadly still the same error message.